# What kind of function may satisfy this set of properties?

Tags: functions

What's an explicit, expressible function that I can program on a computer using basic arithmetic that satisfies the following properties:

$$
f \text{ is differentiable}\\
f(0)=0\\
f(1)=1\\
f′(0)=m_1\\
f′(1)=m_2\\
0≤f(x)≤1\ ∀x∈[0,1]\\
f′(x)≥0
$$

I've messed around with some simple polynomial functions of degree 3, 4, 5, and 6 but none of them satisfy the last two properties. I also considered functions of the following forms:
$$
x^a + (1 - x)^b \\
\frac{1}{2^b}(x^a + (1 + x)^b - 1) \\
\frac{1}{2^b}x^a(1+x)^b
$$

None of these provide strong solutions however.

Any ideas?

Comment: I find questions of the form "I am not quite sure what I mean, so I leave that to the reader" a poor fit for this site.

Comment: How may I improve my question? I'm simply looking for a function that satisfies the given requirements.

Comment: There are infinitely many functions satisfying the requirements. You would need to make a rigorous definition of what you mean by "simplest", which you have already stated you do not want to do.

Comment: You can take a piecewise linear function actually (with three pieces).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Better?

Comment: @timmbob That would be nice if I didn't forget to include the property that $f$ is continuous, sorry!

Comment: @user3002473 continuity is not a problem, the problem is differentiability on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @timmbob you're right again, thank you.

Comment: Take this piecewise linear function suggested by timmbob and convolve it with a standard mollifier.

Comment: @frog Mind elaborating in an answer? I'm not too familiar with convolutions and mollifiers.

Comment: You want monotonic interpolation of Hermite data. Google is shockingly unhelpful at finding a derivation, though it's surely a standard problem (the main difficulty is that "monotonic Hermite interpolation" seems to be an overloaded term). Probably you can cook up a quartic polynomial that does what you need.

Comment: Also, this problem is more interesting than some of the comments above might suggest. The right question to ask is not "can someone find any old function satisfying these constraints" but rather, "what is the right measure for which function is "best" at satisfying these constraints"? The natural choice of the Dirichlet energy $\int_0^1 f'(x)^2$ will not work, as a minimizer does not exist. What, then, is the right energy? It's worth thinking about.

Comment: Have you tried a function of form: $y=a \arctan(kx+h)+b$? I've not verified but maybe that it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's my suggestion in more detail. In order to produce a picture I chose $m_1=2$ and $m_2=4$. Let

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}2x&x\in(-\infty,\frac{1}{4}]\\\frac{1}{2}&x\in[\frac{1}{4},\frac{7}{8}]\\ 4x-3&x\in[\frac{7}{8},\infty)\end{cases}$$

This looks as follows on $[0,1]$:

[image]

Of course you will have to choose $f$ depending on $m_1$ and $m_2$: Sometimes a piecewise linear function with 2 pieces is enough. Then choose a symmetric mollifier, that is a function $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(0,1)$ with the property that
$$
\int_0^1\varphi(x) \,\mathrm dx = 1
$$
Then you can check, that the function
$$
g(x):=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon\varphi\left(\frac{y}{\varepsilon}\right)f(x-y)\,\mathrm dy
$$
leaves $f$ unchanged near $0$ and $1$ provided $\varepsilon$ is small enough, (here smaller than $\frac{1}{4}$) and $g$ is smooth by definition. The plot with the choice $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{6}$ looks as follows:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: "I hope this helps" - very much so. Thank you! If the initial piecewise function I chose was concave or convex, would the resulting convolution maintain concavity/convexity?

Comment: Yes, if you start with a convex or concave (piecewise linear) function, you will get a convex or concave function again.